# What physical properties affect magnetic attraction between a magnet and a surface?

Tags: forces, magnetic-fields

What physical properties of a metal affect how strongly a given permanent magnet will be attracted to the metal?

How do these properties relate to real-world materials that can be purchased either as stamped parts or as cast parts?

I do know that distance matters, and that magnetic strength will fall off roughly at 1/r^3 (the cube of the distance, for human scale distances).  And for cast parts I'm aware that details of the annealing can affect the magnetic permeability and thus perhaps the attractive force for a given magnet.  Here I'm looking for the right words to purchase metal that makes for a good base to stick magnets to.

Comment: Welcome to Physics.SE. Please note, that this site does not deal with engineering. Your question is about engineering, rather than the physical concepts relevant for your project, I therefore voted to close it. Please consider reading [which questions are considered on-topic](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: The question has been reworded to remove the engineering, and focus on the physical properties.